# How to group bytes to message in an reactive way

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive

Assume we have an output-only Stream, which outputs bytes. The data from Stream are serialized messages, each message always starts with a byte sequence (`0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC`), but the length of the message is unknown.

Currently, I created an Observable and emit each byte on the stream, then subscribe to this observable, buffer every emission, find the byte sequence, and then emit the buffer. Something like

```
List<byte> buffer = new List<byte>();
dataStream.subscribe(b => {
    buffer.add(b);
    int[] idx = SearchSequence(buffer);
    if(idx.Length < 2){
        // TODO: wait for more data
    }
    else{
        messageStream.onNext(buffer.GetRange(idx[0], idx[1]));
        // TODO: remove them from buffer
    }
})
```

Is there any more elegant way to solve this issue? There are two concerns as far as I know of:

1. The length of message is not fixed, which invalidate Observable.buffer()
2. At the time when dataStream (or other observable derived from it) is subscribed, the output of Stream may in the middle of a message.

UPDATE:

> How do you detect the end of a message?

There is not gap between messages, the messages are comes right next to each other. Thus, the starting sequence of a message (`0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC`) is also the ending sequence of the previous message

> What does your input observable look like?

My current code is like:

```
Observer<byte> ob = null;
var dataStream = Observable.Create<byte>(o => ob = o);
while(true){
    ob.OnNext(ms.ReadByte());
}
```

> What do you want your output observable to look like?

A observable which emits message

```
Observable<byte[]>
```

Comment: This is fairly unclear. How do you detect the end of a message? What does your input observable look like? What do you want your output observable to look like?

Comment: @Shlomo Sorry about that. I have responded your questions in the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how elegant this is, but maybe it will get you (or others) started. I'm assuming you want the `(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC)` header excluded from the messages:

```
var s = new Subject<byte>();

IObservable<byte[]> results = s.Publish(_s => Observable.When(_s
        .And(_s.Skip(1))
        .And(_s.Skip(2))
        .Then((a, b, c) => (a, b, c))
    ))
    .Publish(_t => _t
        .Buffer(_t.Where(t => t.a == 0xAA && t.b == 0xBB && t.c == 0xCC))
        .Select(l => (l[l.Count - 1].a == 0xAA && l[l.Count - 1].b == 0xBB && l[l.Count - 1].c == 0xCC
                ? l.Take(l.Count - 3)
                : l
            )
            .Select(e => e.c)
            .ToArray()
        )
        .Skip(1)
    )
;
```

Explanation:

We first use `And/Then/When` to do a double zip, so the stream `(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03)` becomes a stream of tuples that look like this:

```
(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC)
(0xBB, 0xCC, 0x01)
(0xCC, 0x01, 0x02)
(0x01, 0x02, 0x03)
(0x02, 0x03, 0xAA)
(0x03, 0xAA, 0xBB)
(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC)
(0xBB, 0xCC, 0x01)
(0xCC, 0x01, 0x02)
(0x01, 0x02, 0x03)
```

We then use `.Where` to sniff out when you have a tuple that looks like `(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC)`, and use that as a buffer boundary.

Once you have your buffer boundaries, they actually cut off *after* the message starter occurs, so you end up for our sample stream of two messages, you end up with three lists of tuples:

```
List 1: (0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC)

List 2: (0xBB, 0xCC, 0x01)
        (0xCC, 0x01, 0x02)
        (0x01, 0x02, 0x03)
        (0x02, 0x03, 0xAA)
        (0x03, 0xAA, 0xBB)
        (0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC)

List 3: (0xBB, 0xCC, 0x01)
        (0xCC, 0x01, 0x02)
        (0x01, 0x02, 0x03)
```

The bytes we want in each list are basically the third column, but if we want to exclude the message-introduction from the messages, then we have to do some cleanup: We have to exclude the last three elements from list 2 (and all other 'middle' lists), we have to remove list 1, and we have to preserve list 3. Removing the first list is accomplished by the `.Skip(1)` at the end. Stripping out the last three elements from middle lists is done by checking to see if the last element in the list is `(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC)`, and if it is, taking all elements except the last three.

Given all that, I hope there's a better way to do this.

Here's some runner code:

```
results.Dump(); //Linqpad

s.OnNext(0xAA);
s.OnNext(0xBB);
s.OnNext(0xCC);
s.OnNext(0x01);
s.OnNext(0x02);
s.OnNext(0x03);

s.OnNext(0xAA);
s.OnNext(0xBB);
s.OnNext(0xCC);

s.OnNext(0xAA);
s.OnNext(0xBB);
s.OnNext(0xCC);
s.OnNext(0x01);
s.OnNext(0x02);
s.OnNext(0x03);
s.OnNext(0xAA);
s.OnNext(0xBB);

s.OnNext(0xAA);
s.OnNext(0xBB);
s.OnNext(0xCC);
s.OnNext(0xCC);
s.OnNext(0xAA);
s.OnNext(0xBB);
s.OnNext(0x04);
s.OnNext(0x05);
s.OnNext(0x06);
s.OnNext(0x07);
s.OnCompleted();
```

Output:

```
01 02 03 

01 02 03 AA BB 
CC AA BB 04 05 06 07
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom `Window` operator that splits a sequence to sub-sequences, according to the supplied separator array. It is based on the built-in `Window` operator that accepts a `IObservable<TWindowBoundary> windowBoundaries` parameter.

```
/// <summary>Projects each element of an observable sequence into non-overlapping
/// windows that are separated by the provided separator.</summary>
public static IObservable<IObservable<T>> Window<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source,
    T[] separator,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    return Observable.Defer(() =>
    {
        var boundaries = new Subject<Unit>();
        var queue = new Queue<T>(separator.Length);
        return source
            .Do(x =>
            {
                if (queue.Count == separator.Length) queue.Dequeue();
                queue.Enqueue(x);
                if (queue.SequenceEqual(separator, comparer))
                {
                    queue.Clear();
                    boundaries.OnNext(default);
                }
            })
            .Concat(Observable.Repeat(default(T), separator.Length - 1))
            .SkipLast(separator.Length - 1)
            .Window(boundaries)
            .Select((window, i) => i == 0 ? window : window.Skip(separator.Length));
    });
}
```

A `Subject` is used for notifying the `Window` operator that a new boundary has been detected. The detection mechanism includes a `Queue` that holds the last emitted elements. This queue is compared to the `separator` every time a new element is emitted. The `Window` operator is lagging intentionally behind the detection mechanism by `separator.Length - 1` elements, so that the resulting windows are aligned properly.

Usage example:

```
IObservable<byte> dataStream = GetDataStream();

IObservable<byte[]> messageStream = dataStream
    .Window(new byte[] { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC })
    .SelectMany(window => window.ToArray());
```